# How do I run c++ programs without opening code::blocks?

Tags: c++

I have just finished making my first working program (not a hello world program), and I want to be able to run it without opening the program files. I currently use Code::Blocks to code, and there is no way (that I've found) that do that.
     What I am talking about, is instead of opening the file, waiting a while (I have a potato) and then clicking run, just to click a desktop icon, which instantly opens the console, and runs the program.

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/263820-how-to-make-an-exe-file-in-codeblocks/

Comment: Don't set it to run by code::blocks by default then

Comment: Nice one! Wish i couldve done that when i was 14. You'll need to make an executable file to run it.

Answer (score 2):

When you are building you application, it creates a folder named "Debug" or "Release" inside your project folder, depends wich target you build. Inside the folder you will find your final executable.